# How to upload themes to wordpress hosted on heroku

Tags: wordpress, heroku

Google recently pulled the plug from Cloud SQL free quota and i am now looking for options other that Amazon EC2 as i don't have a credit yet.

I followed the project https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku and i was able to 
to get wordpress hosted on heroku for free http://calm-wave-7249.herokuapp.com/

The next thing that is bugging me is the ability to add new themes from sites like themeforest.com.

As heroku doesn't support file  I/O i was wondering how to commit and push a theme enabled wordpress instance to my heroku repo.

Any help is this regard would be appreciated.